# How to Escape php line to validete on envato theme check?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, escaping, redux-framework

Got a warning in envato theme checker that it should be escaped.

This is the error

**Found echo $ in the file abc.php. Possible data validation issues found. All dynamic data must be correctly escaped for the context where it is rendered.**

this is the error code

**`echo $this->parent->section_menu ( $k, $section );`**

I understand that it should be escaped, but I don't know how to apply escape to this kind of code. I successfully applied `echo esc_html($variable);` but doing same to above line seems troublesome.

I tried,

`<?php echo esc_attr( $this->parent->section_menu ( $k, $section )); ?>`

`<?php  echo __($this->parent->section_menu ( $k, $section ) );?>`

`<?php echo $this->parent->section_menu ( esc_attr( $k) , esc_attr($section) ); ?>`

but it's not working and messing up the view. can someone help me?

Comment: What does “messing up the view” mean, exactly? And what does this method return in the first place? If it does return properly encoded output already, then encoding it a second time would obviously be wrong.

Comment: I think it shouldnt be escaped since if I used above escape methods, then it shows mixed characters and text. it's just envato theme check plugun shows some errors/warnings when we use echo $vaiable anywhere